# How can I find the element's color on :hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I use [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin and as you see in image below, the `:hover`'s color for `<li>` is a chromatic **blue**. All I'm trying to do is changing it to **red** color.

[image]

---

I worked on it by *Chrome inspect tool* and I figured it out which that color comes from the `highlight` class. See:

[image]

Ok, I've change it to `red`, but still `<li>`'s hover is blue. How can I change it?

[Here](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css) is the `.css` file and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/fosb6meu/) is a demo.

Comment: There is `:hov` at the right top corner in the styles panel. If it's a class and has rules you should find it in the normal list.

Comment: @Pangloss Yes I know, I used it and figured it out which hover color is `background-color: #3875d7;`. I changed it to `red`. but still it is `#3875d7`.

Comment: When u mouse over the item and it turns blue it gets a class "highlighted" if you can find this in the css you should be able to edit

Comment: @stack From the screenshot I can see it's set in `linear-gradient`, so that *override* the `background-color`. What you can try is `background: red none;`.

Answer (score 2):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/fosb6meu/55/)

The reason why it wasn't working when you were trying to change the style from your CSS was because, from the inspector, I could see that the styles for `.highlighted` was applied through an inline CSS which was overriding all the other styles. To overcome that, use `!important` in your CSS.

Also, the blue color that was shown was not just the `background-color`. Instead, it was a `background-image`. Thus you will have to override the `background-image` too..

Thus, add the below given styles to your CSS to change the hover color to `red`.

```
.highlighted{
  background-color:red !important;
  background-image:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as Lal said, please check also `background-image`:

```
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,50% 0,50% 100%,color-stop(20%,#3875d7),color-stop(90%,#2a62bc));
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%,#2a62bc 90%);
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%,#2a62bc 90%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%,#2a62bc 90%);
background-image:linear-gradient(#3875d7 20%,#2a62bc 90%);
```

There are linear gradients so maybe you want to change blue color #3875d7 to the color you want? You need to change corresponding second color of gradient also {#2a62bc}

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the color it sets in the [CSS](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.min.css) that chosen provides for you? Open up the file, ctrl-f color if you need to and just find that blue, swap the # value for a red one that you want.

And if you want to be lazy just find every instance of the blue and change it to red so you don't worry about it sometimes being blue and sometimes red.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the css. You may define this in your page's css rather than modifying the Chosen CSS because it's not meant to be modified, other developers might need to use the same library in your codebase

```
  .chosen-container .chosen-results li.highlighted {
       background-color: #dc2951 !important;
       background-image: none;
  }
```

[image]